# Get list of available options in a select field of custom content type

Tags: forms, 8, entities, blocks

I created a custom content type called 'slide' that has a custom select field called 'field_category'. I would like to be able to load the available options of 'field_category' into the select field of a block form.

I'm currently attempting to follow the instructions of an answer to a similar question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182062/programmatically-get-the-list-of-fields-of-a-custom-content) but I'm still having trouble.

I'm grabbing the content type definitions like so

```
$definitions = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'slide');
```

However when I spit out

```
print_r($definitions->getFieldDefinition('field_category'))
```

I can't actually find any of the options to grab. Is there a way to grab the available options of a field of a custom content type programmatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$definitions = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'slide');
$definition = $definitions['field_category'];
$settings = $definition->getSettings();
$allowed_values = $settings['allowed_values'];
```